# Uppercase the names of multiple files in a directory in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, uppercase

I'm working on a small project that requires that I use Python to uppercase all the names of files in a certain directory "ex: input: Brandy.jpg , output: BRANDY.jpg".
The thing is I've never done on multiple files before, what I've done was the following:

```
universe = os.listdir('parallel_universe/')
universe = [os.path.splitext(x)[0].upper() for x in universe]
```

But what I've done capitalized the names in the list only but not the files in the directory itself, the output was like the following:

```
['ADAM SANDLER','ANGELINA JULIE','ARIANA GRANDE','BEN AFFLECK','BEN STILLER','BILL GATES', 'BRAD PITT','BRITNEY SPEARS','BRUCE LEE','CAMERON DIAZ','DWAYNE JOHNSON','ELON MUSK','ELTON JOHN','JACK BLACK','JACKIE CHAN','JAMIE FOXX','JASON SEGEL', 'JASON STATHAM']
```

What am I missing here? And since I don't have much experience in Python, I'd love if your answers include explanations for each step, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are converting the strings to uppercase, but that's it. There is no actual renaming being done. In order to rename, you need to use `os.rename`

If you were to wrap your code with `os.rename`, it should solve your problem, like so:

```
[os.rename("parallel_universe/" + x, "parallel_universe/" + os.path.splitext(x)[0].upper() + os.path.splitext(x)[1]) for x in universe]
```

I have removed the assignment `universe=` because this line no longer returns a list and you will instead get a bunch on `None` objects.

Docs for `os.rename`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename